# Get recommendation videos from youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, request

I need to get some recommended videos for loggined user from youtube api. I am using this request

```
 GET GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&home=true&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But in response i receive only 4 videos and all the same in every request. So how do i get all recommended videos i want?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the videos from your subscribed channels with that request. You can also try chart=mostpopular for most popular videos.

More info:
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/09/what-to-watch-our-apis-can-help.html

Comment: i did already subscribes and most popular. But now i want to get videos exactly from this "Recommendation" channel https://www.youtube.com/feed/recommended